# Javascript not working properly after routing in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have this script included in my index.html to append the following in my Page A

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var tabe = document.getElementsByClassName("id-column");
    tabe[0].innerHTML += "HI"; 
});        
</script>
```

This works fine when the page is loaded for first time , but when i route to Page B and go to Page A again , this script has no effect !! Is there a solution to this issue ?

Comment: You should probably try to set the innerHtml in an angular way. There are things like @ViewChild to access the DOM properly. Other services like Renderer2 can even help you to create new html tags dynamically. Accessing or even altering the DOM outside of the angular should never be the way you should go.

Comment: The element with "id-column" is itself created dynamically through data table , is it possible for me to implement your way of appending through Renderer2 for dynamic elements too ? @BenediktSchmidt

Comment: It probably depends on what you are trying to do. With @ViewChild you can set a reference to some point of your html, maybe the last div parent of your table that you define yourself (i guess you put the data table inside of some html tag, you could use that) . With lifecycle hooks like afterViewInit you can wait till your data table is rendered through angular. After that you can access your referenced element and can do multiple things on it like querying its childs just like jquery or simply run through all of its childs with elementRef.childNodes. Then you can alter the html for example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543482/5634712 the question here is different but there are some code examples in my answer that could possibly give you a hint on how to solve your problem with angular instead of plain javascript DOM manipulation. Just ask if you need some help

Comment: Mate its a fine example you have got there , but i have one doubt 'this.markdownDiv.nativeElement.querySelector("a");' , in this case it is based on tag element <a> but what if i want it based on class name for a particular column in table

Comment: Can't figure out why someone would downvote a genuine question without proper explanation :(

Comment: You can probably use `this.elementRef.nativeElement.query(".id-colum")` as a selector.

Comment: will try out this implementation mate :)